# Try-catch is not working for 400 errors in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, try-catch

This is getting on my nerves, I've been checking the code for a few hours and can't spot the problem. in the below code, I'm using an invalid object in the body in order to get 400 error (Bad Request) and therefore catch it in the catch block:

```
  <button onClick={() => {
    try {
      axiosInstance.post('/cart', { field: "invalid field" });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("here!!!"); 
      console.error(err);
    }
  }}
  />
```

I can see the request fail in network tab, in console I can see:

```
POST http://api.[REDACTED]/api/cart 400 (Bad Request)
index.js:1375 Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

Comment: can you post your axiosInstance, i feel some issue in the headers, and what all headers does the back end requires, did you tried posting using postman is it working in it

Comment: As Travis mentioned since doesn't have the issue with headers kindly check the answer posted by Travis and let us know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Axios http requests are async, you need to use `Promises` or `async/await`.  Try this and you will see the error response:

```
<button onClick={async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.post('/cart', { field: "invalid field" });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("here!!!"); 
      console.error(err);
      console.error(err.response);
    }
  }}
  />
```

Comment: But before going to this, the request is bad which means something wrong in the headers !! Correct me if i am wrong @Travis

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS You are wrong.  It doesn't have anything to do with headers

Comment: No problem, headers can be an issue but it would be a separate issue

Comment: But i thought since the status code is because of 400 it can be issue by us which means who sends it so it can be headers issue, cool great info  :)

Answer (score 1):

Https requests are asynchronous, you need to make the handler async and await the result of the call.

```
  <button
    onClick={async () => {
      try {
        return await axiosInstance.post('/cart', { field: "invalid field" });;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }}
  >
    async press me
  </button>
```

The following sandbox shows each side-by-side.

[image: Edit strange-pine-ozzq1]

Answer (score 0):

If this error response don't show "here!!" In console, certainly the error is caused before this code section, probably in axios declaration or axios request form.

Try configure axios options inside a json object like:

axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "..."